# Do you need to manually remove a connection from a SignalR group on disconnect?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

In a SignalR hub, I am adding connections to groups in the `OnConnected` method:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, "aGroup");
    this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, "bGroup");
}
```

Do I need to manually remove the connection from these groups upon disconnect? Given the pub-sub model, I don't see how I could easily do this, except to keep track of connections and groups in a separate data structure.

I am experiencing a rather large memory leak in an MVC project using SignalR, and am wondering if this could be the culprit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you don't.

> You don't have to explicitly create groups. In effect, a group is
>   automatically created the first time you specify its name in a call to
>   Groups.Add, **and it is deleted when you remove the last connection from
>   membership in it**.

Source, and read further: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Comment: Thanks, @DDan. Maybe that's just awkwardly worded, but the information you cite seems to be saying that you ARE supposed to remove connections from group membership. Only when that last connection is removed is the group deleted.

Comment: Later, the same page you referenced goes on to say, `You do not need to manually remove a user from a group when the connection ends.` So the long and short of it seems to be that SignalR automatically takes care of removing the connection from the group when the connection ends, so you do not have to worry about this.

Comment: How did you fix the memory leak ?